# HIGHCHARTS plotlines with marker like cross hairs

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I have created a graph using high charts functionalities in live streaming data. At the end of the data I have to show a plotline in Y Axis. But at the end of the line I would like to get a marker just like as cross hairs.

Here is my code:

```
var chart = $('#container').highcharts();
                  chart.yAxis[0].removePlotLine('hori_line');
                    data = chart.series[0].data;
                    var test = data.length;
                    var value = data[999].y.toFixed(6);
                    chart.yAxis[0].addPlotLine({
                    value: value,
                    width: 2 ,  
                    color: '#248EC6',
                    id: 'hori_line',
                    padding: 8,
                    label: {
                      text: value,
                      align: 'right',
                      style: {
                        color: '#FFFFFF',
                        fontWeight: 'bold',

                      }
                    }

                    });
```

Here is the output what am getting now.

[image]

Comment: Could you post live example of your chart? Like jsFiddle? Maybe you can use renderer options for making 'custom' plotLine label? http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Renderer

Comment: @GrzegorzBlachliński https://jsfiddle.net/Pilaventhiran/gxvk81xm/

Comment: Thank you for this example. I think that the best idea is to use renderer.label option. Here you can find an API for this method: http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#Renderer.label
And here you can find an example how it can work:
http://jsfiddle.net/3qfrke8t/1/